# How do I use a custom constructor in a WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to instantiate a Winform within another project. How is this done? I am currently attempting to chain the default constructor. It seems that my custom constructor is not called.

Also.. the entry point for this application will not be in the project that owns this form. Meaning the following will not run:

```
 Application.EnableVisualStyles();
 Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
 Application.Run(new HtmlTestForm());
```

I am not entirely sure what this code is doing. Will the form still function?

```
private HtmlTestForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OpenBrowser(new Uri(TestURL));
        }

 public HtmlTestForm(Uri uri)
            :this()
        {
            TestURL = uri;
        }
```

//New up form in another project.

```
HtmlTestForm form = new HtmlTestForm(new Uri("http://SomeUri.html"));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The form will work.
However, `TestURL` will only be assigned after the `OpenBrowser` call.  (`: this()` will execute the entire default constructor first)

Instead, you should probably call `InitializeComponent` separately in your custom constructor and not chain to the default.

.Net form classes are normal classes that happen to contain an automatically generated method called `InitializeComponent`.
**They do not have any magic** that you need to be aware of (unlike VB6); as long as you understand the purpose of `InitializeComponent` (read its source), you can do anything you want with them.

Comment: The one bit of "magic" involved is that forms are automatically created by the Windows Forms designer... which requires a parameterless constructor, I believe.

Comment: @Jon: No, it doesn't.  The designer only instantiates your form if you open a form that inherits from it in Design view.  If you don't inherit from your form, it doesn't need a parameterless constructor.

Comment: gosh, that's welcome news. Will edit answer when I get the chance.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. I also thought the parameterless constructor was required.

Comment: ... Unless you're making a user control, and you want to be able to drag it onto the designer from the toolbox. Then you also need a parameterless constructor.

Comment: The designer simply reads and interprets the *.designer.cs file. Try to create textboxes in a for loop in `InitializeComponent`. This does not work. If the designer would instantiate the form and run `InitializeComponent` instead, this would work.